# Crash Report is not showing the code line of a crash in a background thread

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I'm learning how to analyse crash reports. I'm purposely adding bugs to my swift app code and looking at the resultant crash reports. When the bug is in a block of code run in a background async thread the crash report does not identify the code line number of the crash.

Is it possible to get this line number from the crash?

Here's part of the crash report:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001020791fc
Triggered by Thread:  5

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
2.965970     AppleJPEG                  0x000000018300e26c [0x13e05f000] Created session



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   QuartzCore                      0x00000001840921f4 slab_alloc + 392
1   QuartzCore                      0x0000000184092058 magazine_alloc_ + 304
2   QuartzCore                      0x0000000184092058 magazine_alloc_ + 304
3   QuartzCore                      0x000000018408eee8 x_mem_alloc_bucket + 144
4   QuartzCore                      0x000000018408eb94 CA::AttrList::set(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 160
5   QuartzCore                      0x0000000184092398 CA::Layer::setter(unsigned int, _CAValueType, void const*) + 208
6   QuartzCore                      0x0000000184099ec4 -[CALayer setOpacity:] + 48
7   UIKit                           0x00000001869a7678 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 + 1072
8   UIKit                           0x000000018671b5b4 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 80
9   UIKit                           0x00000001869068d4 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke + 260
10  UIKit                           0x0000000186a26334 +[UIView(Internal) _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] + 220
11  UIKit                           0x000000018690644c -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] + 1060
12  UIKit                           0x00000001868c0818 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 3544
13  UIKit                           0x00000001867cbe40 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
14  UIKit                           0x00000001867cbb1c -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
15  UIKit                           0x00000001867cba84 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
16  UIKit                           0x00000001867081e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
17  QuartzCore                      0x000000018409a994 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
18  QuartzCore                      0x00000001840955d0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
19  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184095490 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
20  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184094ac0 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
21  QuartzCore                      0x0000000184094820 CA::Transaction::commit() + 500
22  QuartzCore                      0x000000018408dde4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 80
23  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181564728 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815624cc __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001815628fc __CFRunLoopRun + 928
26  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018148cc50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
27  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182d74088 GSEventRunModal + 180
28  UIKit                           0x0000000186776088 UIApplicationMain + 204
29  MargRiver                       0x00000001000fc378 main (AppDelegate.swift:27)
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x000000018102a8b8 start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001811494d8 kevent_qos + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018100c7d8 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 232
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ffb648 _dispatch_source_invoke + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181148b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181148b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181148b48 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211530 _pthread_wqthread + 1284
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.background-qos
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001020791fc 0x101f38000 + 1315324
1   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001020791fc 0x101f38000 + 1315324
2   MargRiver                       0x00000001000ea908 EntriesListController.(loadEntries(completion : () -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (EntriesListController.swift:0)
3   MargRiver                       0x00000001000ae798 thunk (MoreViewController.swift:0)
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ff94bc _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ff947c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181007914 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2140
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001810070b0 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 112
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181211020 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001028d1400   x1: 0x000000018120a8f4   x2: 0x000000013d512300   x3: 0x0000000000000008
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000000010   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x00000001028d1408   x9: 0x0000000000001000  x10: 0x000000013d514000  x11: 0x0000000000000fff
   x12: 0x000000013d510000  x13: 0x0000000000003fff  x14: 0xffffffffffffc000  x15: 0x0000000000003fff
   x16: 0x0000000181174168  x17: 0x000000010215c048  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000000000002  x21: 0x0000000000000039  x22: 0x0000000100727500  x23: 0x0000000000000002
   x24: 0x000000000000000b  x25: 0x000000010072753a  x26: 0x000000016e2470e0  x27: 0x000000016e2470e0
   x28: 0x0000000000000000  fp: 0x000000016e246720   lr: 0x00000001020791fc
    sp: 0x000000016e2466e0   pc: 0x00000001020791fc cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Here is the beginning of the loadEntries() function:

```
fileprivate func loadEntries(completion: (() -> Void)?) -> Void {
    let timeStartDb = Date()
    var timeEndDb: Date!
    var sqlStatement: String!
    var newEntries = [Entry]()
    var newSelectedSegment = false // true => the selected segment control button is different from last time loadEntries() was called

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

        if (self.listOrderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex != self.previousSelectedSegmentIndex) {
           newSelectedSegment = true
           self.previousSelectedSegmentIndex = self.listOrderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex
        }

        switch (self.listOrderSegControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case EntriesListController.LIST_ORDER_DISTANCE:
            sqlStatement = self.sqlSubStatement + self.distanceSortOrder
        case EntriesListController.LIST_ORDER_AZ:
            sqlStatement = self.sqlSubStatement + "title"
        case EntriesListController.LIST_ORDER_RECOMMENDED:
            sqlStatement = self.sqlSubStatement + "prio"
        default:
            sqlStatement = self.sqlSubStatement + "prio"
            self.previousSelectedSegmentIndex = EntriesListController.LIST_ORDER_RECOMMENDED
        }
```

The code crashes in the switch statement because self.sqlSubStatement=nil. As I mentioned above, I've purposely added this bug in order to learn how to use crash reports. The crash report is however not identifying the line of code with the bug. Can it be made to identify it?